# define non-overriable associated type in trait?

Tags: rust

I'd like to define an associated type in a trait (`B::X` in the example) as a shorter alias to another nameable type (`<B::Y as A>::X` in the example). I can do so with a default associated type, however the fact that the default is overridable means that I can't rely on it being a simple alias. Is there a way to make the default non-overridable?

```
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]
trait A {
    type X;
}
trait B {
    type Y: A;
    type X = <Self::Y as A>::X;
}

impl A for usize {
    type X = usize;
}

impl B for usize {
    type Y = usize;
    type X = isize; // this should not be allowed!
}

// allowed, correct, but verbose
type Baz = <<usize as B>::Y as A>::X;

// correct, concise, but not allowed, "ambiguous associated type"
type Bar = <usize as B>::Y::X;

// allowed, but because B::X is overridable, it lies!
type Foo = <usize as B>::X;
```

playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=847a8ac522ddee93dc898a3771fed8f3

Comment: You could declare a helper type alias outside the trait, e.g. `type BX<T> = <<T as B>::Y as A>::X;`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b48adaefd42601b50b764e8b3cd8f218)

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a helper type alias outside the trait, e.g. `type BX<T> = <<T as B>::Y as A>::X;`

```
use std::any::type_name;

trait A {
    type X;
}

trait B {
    type Y: A;
}

type BX<T> = <<T as B>::Y as A>::X;

impl A for usize {
    type X = usize;
}

impl B for usize {
    type Y = usize;
}

fn main() {
    // Prints usize
    println!("{}", type_name::<<<usize as B>::Y as A>::X>());
    // Also prints usize
    println!("{}", type_name::<BX<usize>>());
    
    // Fails to compile; `B` is not implemented for `char`
    // println!("{}", type_name::<BX<char>>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b48adaefd42601b50b764e8b3cd8f218)